Plotting star maps with equatorial coordinates system
I'm trying to generate star maps with the equatorial coordinates system (RAJ2000 and DEJ2000). However, I only get a grid system where meridians and parallels are in parallel, while parallels should be curved and meridians should converge to the north celestial pole and the south ceestial pole.
I'm using some Python modules: matplotlib, skyfield (for the stereographic projection), astroquery (so I can target any object in the deep space) and astropy.
This is my code:
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Generate a skymap with equatorial grid"""

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from skyfield.api import Star, load
from skyfield.data import hipparcos, stellarium
from skyfield.projections import build_stereographic_projection
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
import astropy.units as u
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.visualization.wcsaxes import WCSAxes

# Design
plt.style.use("dark_background")
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Times New Roman']

# Query object from Simbad
OBJECT = "Alioth"
FOV = 30.0
MAG = 6.5

TABLE = Simbad.query_object(OBJECT)
RA = TABLE['RA'][0]
DEC = TABLE['DEC'][0]
COORD = SkyCoord(f"{RA} {DEC}", unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg), frame='fk5')

print("RA is", RA)
print("DEC is", DEC)

ts = load.timescale()
t = ts.now()

# An ephemeris from the JPL provides Sun and Earth positions.
eph = load('de421.bsp')
earth = eph['earth']

# Load constellation outlines from Stellarium
url = ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Stellarium/stellarium/master'
       '/skycultures/modern_st/constellationship.fab')

with load.open(url) as f:
    constellations = stellarium.parse_constellations(f)

edges = [edge for name, edges in constellations for edge in edges]
edges_star1 = [star1 for star1, star2 in edges]
edges_star2 = [star2 for star1, star2 in edges]

# The Hipparcos mission provides our star catalog.
with load.open(hipparcos.URL) as f:
    stars = hipparcos.load_dataframe(f)

# Center the chart on the specified object's position.
center = earth.at(t).observe(Star(ra_hours=COORD.ra.hour, dec_degrees=COORD.dec.degree))
projection = build_stereographic_projection(center)

# Compute the x and y coordinates that each star will have on the plot.
star_positions = earth.at(t).observe(Star.from_dataframe(stars))
stars['x'], stars['y'] = projection(star_positions)

# Create a True/False mask marking the stars bright enough to be included in our plot.
bright_stars = (stars.magnitude <= MAG)
magnitude = stars['magnitude'][bright_stars]
marker_size = (0.5 + MAG - magnitude) ** 2.0

# The constellation lines will each begin at the x,y of one star and end at the x,y of another.
xy1 = stars[['x', 'y']].loc[edges_star1].values
xy2 = stars[['x', 'y']].loc[edges_star2].values
lines_xy = np.rollaxis(np.array([xy1, xy2]), 1)

# Define the limit for the plotting area
angle = np.deg2rad(FOV / 2.0)
limit = np.tan(angle)  # Calculate limit based on the field of view

# Build the figure with WCS axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[6, 6])
wcs = WCS(naxis=2)
wcs.wcs.crpix = [1, 1]
wcs.wcs.cdelt = np.array([-FOV / 360, FOV / 360])
wcs.wcs.crval = [COORD.ra.deg, COORD.dec.deg]
wcs.wcs.ctype = ["RA---STG", "DEC--STG"]

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=wcs)

# Draw the constellation lines
ax.add_collection(LineCollection(lines_xy, colors='#ff7f2a', linewidths=1, linestyle='-'))

# Draw the stars
ax.scatter(stars['x'][bright_stars], stars['y'][bright_stars],
           s=marker_size, color='white', zorder=2)

ax.scatter(RA, DEC, marker='*', color='red', zorder=3)

angle = np.pi - FOV / 360.0 * np.pi
limit = np.sin(angle) / (1.0 - np.cos(angle))

# Set plot limits
ax.set_xlim(-limit, limit)
ax.set_ylim(-limit, limit)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# Add RA/Dec grid lines
ax.coords.grid(True, color='white', linestyle='dotted')

# Set the coordinate grid
ax.coords[0].set_axislabel('RA (hours)')
ax.coords[1].set_axislabel('Dec (degrees)')
ax.coords[0].set_major_formatter('hh:mm:ss')
ax.coords[1].set_major_formatter('dd:mm:ss')

# Title
ax.set_title(f'Sky map centered on {OBJECT}', color='white', y=1.04)

# Save the image
FILE = "chart.png"
plt.savefig(FILE, dpi=100, facecolor='#1a1a1a')

And this is the resulting image:

As you can see, the grid (parallels and meridians) are totally parallel. However, my goal is to achieve this grid:

In this case, I got the right WCS from a FITS image in the DSS survey. It's automatic. However, for plotting star maps I need to create a simulation of that, working fine with the labels and the coordinates system, not as a background image or something else.

I would use cartopy to handle the projection. Here is an example from another question https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/54108/35318

Nice example! Thanks, Roy Smart. I'm gonna try it. One cuestion: in this example, you used "Ortographic". Should I use "Stereographic"?

Yeah, I think that should be sufficient. Might need to tweak some parameters to get it to exactly match your example.

I'm stuck trying to install cartopy, though. I'm using Python 3.8. Gonna try 3.9 or 3.10 with pyenv.

BTW, I updated the line with the constellations lines to make it work, since I had the file already downloaded. url = ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Stellarium/stellarium/master'        '/skycultures/modern_st/constellationship.fab')

Dang, I was worried about that. I also find cartopy annoying to install.

I also tried to use Basemap some days ago, but I didn't know how to implement it (if it's really possible, of course).

I'm not able to install cartopy. I even installed a virtual machine with Debian 12 without luck.

You do not need to install something else. Matplotlib provides all the tools you need

I could find the solution in another forum. So I'm gonna post the answer. It was easier than it seems!
The essential problem was in my WCS coordinate scales, they were defined incorrectly. Actually, using the FOV 30, the image didn't have a FOV of 30 degrees, it was smaller. This point helped to find the answer.
There was a problem in the units used. While I was plltting everything in radians, WCSAxes works in pixels, so I needed to define CDELT to be 1 radian per pixel.
So the line corrected is this one:
wcs.wcs.cdelt = np.array([-360 / np.pi, 360 / np.pi])

This is the final image:

I'm very very happy with this!

I can't replicate your code, to show where exactly you need corrections.
Matplotlib allows you to use polar coordinates,for this you need ti apply axes and grids like in those docs: matplotlib docs
If you can simplify code without using files (with just list of numbers or strings, idk), I can try to fix it
The following is a simple example of how you can do this:
    #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Generate a skymap with equatorial grid"""

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from skyfield.api import Star, load
from skyfield.data import hipparcos, stellarium
from skyfield.projections import build_stereographic_projection
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
import astropy.units as u
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.visualization.wcsaxes import WCSAxes
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.projections import PolarAxes
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist import Axes, HostAxes, angle_helper
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.grid_helper_curvelinear import \
    GridHelperCurveLinear

# Design
plt.style.use("dark_background")
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Times New Roman']

# Query object from Simbad
OBJECT = "Polaris"
FOV = 30.0
MAG = 6.5

TABLE = Simbad.query_object(OBJECT)
RA = TABLE['RA'][0]
DEC = TABLE['DEC'][0]
COORD = SkyCoord(f"{RA} {DEC}", unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg), frame='fk5')

print("RA is", RA)
print("DEC is", DEC)

ts = load.timescale()
t = ts.now()

# An ephemeris from the JPL provides Sun and Earth positions.
eph = load('de421.bsp')
earth = eph['earth']

# Load constellation outlines from Stellarium
url = ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Stellarium/stellarium/master'
       '/skycultures/modern_st/constellationship.fab')

with load.open(url) as f:
    constellations = stellarium.parse_constellations(f)

edges = [edge for name, edges in constellations for edge in edges]
edges_star1 = [star1 for star1, star2 in edges]
edges_star2 = [star2 for star1, star2 in edges]

# The Hipparcos mission provides our star catalog.
with load.open(hipparcos.URL) as f:
    stars = hipparcos.load_dataframe(f)

# Center the chart on the specified object's position.
center = earth.at(t).observe(Star(ra_hours=COORD.ra.hour, dec_degrees=COORD.dec.degree))
projection = build_stereographic_projection(center)

# Compute the x and y coordinates that each star will have on the plot.
star_positions = earth.at(t).observe(Star.from_dataframe(stars))
stars['x'], stars['y'] = projection(star_positions)

# Create a True/False mask marking the stars bright enough to be included in our plot.
bright_stars = (stars.magnitude <= MAG)
magnitude = stars['magnitude'][bright_stars]
marker_size = (0.5 + MAG - magnitude) ** 2.0

# The constellation lines will each begin at the x,y of one star and end at the x,y of another.
xy1 = stars[['x', 'y']].loc[edges_star1].values
xy2 = stars[['x', 'y']].loc[edges_star2].values
lines_xy = np.rollaxis(np.array([xy1, xy2]), 1)

# Define the limit for the plotting area
angle = np.deg2rad(FOV / 2.0)
limit = np.tan(angle)  # Calculate limit based on the field of view

# Build the figure with WCS axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[6, 6])
wcs = WCS(naxis=2)
wcs.wcs.crpix = [1, 1]
wcs.wcs.cdelt = np.array([-FOV / 360, FOV / 360])
wcs.wcs.crval = [COORD.ra.deg, COORD.dec.deg]
wcs.wcs.ctype = ["RA---STG", "DEC--STG"]

# <- Start point code implementetion from docs
tr = Affine2D().scale(np.pi/180, 1) + PolarAxes.PolarTransform()
grid_locator1 = angle_helper.LocatorDMS(12)

grid_helper = GridHelperCurveLinear(
    tr, grid_locator1=grid_locator1)

ax = fig.add_subplot(
    1, 1, 1, axes_class=HostAxes, grid_helper=grid_helper)
ax.axis["right"].major_ticklabels.set_visible(True)
ax.axis["top"].major_ticklabels.set_visible(True)
ax.axis["right"].get_helper().nth_coord_ticks = 0
ax.axis["bottom"].get_helper().nth_coord_ticks = 1

ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.grid(True, zorder=0)
ax.grid(True, color='white', linestyle='dotted')
# <- End point code implementetion from docs

# Draw the constellation lines
ax.add_collection(LineCollection(lines_xy, colors='#ff7f2a', linewidths=1, linestyle='-'))

# Draw the stars
ax.scatter(stars['x'][bright_stars], stars['y'][bright_stars],
           s=marker_size, color='white', zorder=2)

ax.scatter(RA, DEC, marker='*', color='red', zorder=3)

angle = np.pi - FOV / 360.0 * np.pi
limit = np.sin(angle) / (1.0 - np.cos(angle))

# Set plot limits
# Also some changes below
ax.set_xlim(-limit, limit)
ax.set_ylim(-limit, limit)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# Add RA/Dec grid lines
ax.grid(True, color='white', linestyle='dotted')

# Set the coordinate grid
ax.set_xlabel('RA (hours)')
ax.set_ylabel('Dec (degrees)')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter('hh:mm:ss')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter('dd:mm:ss')

# Title
ax.set_title(f'Sky map centered on {OBJECT}', color='white', y=1.04)

# Save the image
FILE = "chart.png"
plt.savefig(FILE, dpi=100, facecolor='#1a1a1a')

Maybe I missed something, but it seems ok

Oh I see! Thanks. I'm gonna try it also!

BTW, I updated the line with the constellations lines to make it work, since I had the file already downloaded. url = ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Stellarium/stellarium/master'        '/skycultures/modern_st/constellationship.fab')

BTW I have changed your code, you can try it

Now it looks very good!! However, if you change the target (m42 or m31), it still shows the same axis

Can you show me which target you're talking about so I can see

This script can target any object from the Simbad database (a star, a galaxy, a nebula....) so it can plot a stars chart from that target. In the example above, I used the star "Polaris" because it's easier to see how the grid (parallels and meridians) should appear curved. However, you can try other objects, like "M31", "M42" or "Sirius". It should plot the object centered, with al the stars visible into the specific FOV (that works pretty well) and the curved lines. In my code, grid appears totally parallel, even near to Polaris star, where parallels should be circular.

I updated the images for a better understanding.
